Trigonometry question involving bearings and angle of depression
Lloyd starts a bushwalk from the base of a wind generator, which is $55$m tall and located at point A, which is at sea level. He walks for $4$km on the bearing $060^o$T up a slope that is inclined at $10^o$ to the horizontal to position B, where a fire tower of height $80$m is located.

a. Find to the nearest degree and minute, the angle of depression from the top of the fire tower to the top of the wind generator.

Lloyd then treks $10$km on the bearing $150^o$T down a slope to reach point C at sea level

b. Find the angle of depression from the base of the fire tower to position C.

c. Find the angle of elevation from C to the top of the wind generator

d. Find, to the nearest degree, the bearing of position C from A.



My solution:
I found that the horizontal distance (at sea level) between the two buildings is $4\cos10 = 3.939$km and that the height of the fire tower above sea level is $4\sin10 = 0.69459$km.

From the diagram, I have that $x=774.59-55=719.59$ and so $\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{774.59}{3939} \approx 11^o$
I didn't use the true bearing at all, so worried that I have messed up. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

What does T mean in " ... the bearing $060^o$T up a slope" ?

T means that it is a true bearing.
